# rescue in erb template good practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, rescue

The question it's simple:

It's a good practice use rescue like this?

```
...
    <td><%= @customer.address.city.name rescue "-" %></td>
    <td><%= @customer.address.province.name rescue "-" %></td>
    <td><%= @customer.address.country.name rescue "-" %></td>
...
```

If not, where it's the solution? a "if" before?

Comment: I think the best solution it's exposed by @Зелёный in a comment of NARKOZ post.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`try` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) in Rails:

```
<td><%= @customer.address.city.try(:name) || '-' %></td>
```

In Ruby 2.3+ you can use native [safe navigation operator](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537):

```
<td><%= @customer&.address&.city&.name || '-' %></td>
```

Comment: but if `@customer.address` return `nil` ? my be use `try` chain? like `@customer.address.try(:city).try(:name)`. I do not use `try`

Comment: When you send messages to objects in views that might return `nil` or when the object doesn't respond to that message, that's a problem you should solve on its own. Using `try` only exacerbates the problem, in the same way that `nil`-checking does. Write consistent interfaces that behave consistently.

Comment: Thanks for telling about this nice feature

Answer (score 9):

I think this bad practice, because `rescue` for exceptions and if somewhere happen errors you do not know it.

Use if conditional or ternary operator or something else but do not use rescue for this case:

```
<td><%= @customer.address.city.name if @customer.address %></td>
<td><%=  @customer.address ? @customer.address.city.name : '-' %></td>
```

If you want Rails way move this logic in `ApplicationHelper` or use Drapper gem.

Answer (score 3):

No., Its not a best practice to use rescue in the view pages.

Try the following **ternary operator** of ruby along with **try** method:

...

<%= @customer.try(:address).present? ? @customer.try(:address).try(:city).try(:name) : "-"%>

...

You can also **chain** the **try** method in condition part.

Ternary operator is similar to if else condition, but we need not to go for multiple line coding with if-else.

Hope it helps..

NARKOZ is a way good practice too.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem:

```
...
<td><%= @customer.address.city.name rescue "-" %></td>
<td><%= @customer.address.province.name rescue "-" %></td>
<td><%= @customer.address.country.name rescue "-" %></td>
...
```

The solution:

```
...
<td><%= (@customer.address && @customer.address.city && @customer.address.city.name) || "-" %></td>
<td><%= (@customer.address && @customer.address.province && @customer.address.province.name) || "-" %></td>
<td><%= (@customer.address && @customer.address.country && @customer.address.country.name) || "-" %></td>
...
```

Comment: Could it be even worse than this?